# Time series data with mixed calendar and fiscal year

Tags: regression, time-series, references, econometrics

I am performing time series analysis with yearly frequently. However I need to regress a data compiled by calendar year against another compiled by fiscal year. Is it possible to deal with this? If yes, how do I proceed?

In another case, I compiled a series for an indicator. However, I only was able to compile it with the first part of the series by calendar year, the second by fiscal year and the third part by calendar year (again!). My questions regarding this are the same. Is it possible to deal with this? If yes, how do I proceed?

It would be amazing if you also can suggest some literature where I can read more about this.

Comment: If "fiscal year = calendar year + offset", you can try modeling offset as an input with calendar year data having offset = 0, that might be worth a try.

Comment: @JamesPhillips, why not develop that into an official answer?

Comment: @gung I consider this a simple suggestion to be tried, rather than an actual answer.